# VAE with some inputs set to zero

Tags: neural-networks, autoencoders

I have a VAE based model for processing time-series data from $n$ sensors. However, only $k<n$ sensors are active and have non-zero input data. I'd like to fix the number of inputs in the model to $n$.

In my experiments, I found that I can train the model if I restrict the number of inputs to $k$ (i.e. only feed in non-zero data) and I get: `loss: nan - val_loss: nan` if some of my inputs (non-active sensors) are set to all zeros during training.

I'm wondering why VAE based architecture fails to train when some of the inputs are set to all zeros. How can I remedy this situation? I tried adding noise to zero inputs but it results in the same outcome. Thanks!